# Is "test_code" in "python -m unittest test_code" argument of '-m' or argument of 'unittest'?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am learning python unittest.
I would like to ask what the 'test_code' in the following code is.

```
python -m unittest test_code
```

Is it the argument of '-m' option or one of unittest?
I would like to know how the unittest works.

Thank you very much

Comment: Yes, `test_code` is an argument for `unittest`, it alone is the filename of which the tests are located in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using unittest module you can run tests from modules in command line. While -m is a flag and is used to specify python that you would be using test methods of unittest.